# MockMvc - Pasar un objeto desde el mock al controlador

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, test, junit

Estoy haciendo pruebas unitarias de una aplicación web que estoy desarrollando y me he topado con un problema a la hora de testear algunas de las funciones de los controladores.

Básicamente estoy creando un mockMvc y quiero pasarle un objeto que creo previamente. El código es este:

```
        Connection connection1 = new Connection();
        connection1.setStatus(Status.IN);
        connection1.setConnectionId("countingCamera1Conn");
        connection1.setPath("urlPath");
        connection1.setUsername("userName");
        when(connectionRepoMock.existsById(anyString())).thenReturn(true);

        //then

        mockMvc.perform(post("/model/connection")
                .content(asJsonString(connection1))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
        ;
```

El controlador recibe por parámetro dos objetos. Este controlador es el que usa la vista para crear un nuevo registro del objeto indicado.

```
    @PostMapping("model/connection")
    public String addConnection(Connection connection, Model model) {
        checkRole(model);
        if(!checkElement(connection,model))
            return "error";
        if(controllerRepo.existsById(connection.getConnectionId())) {
            model.addAttribute("errorMsg", "The Id already exists, please try another one");
            return "error";
        }
        controllerRepo.save(connection);
        return "redirect:/model/connection";
    }
```

He comprobado que si en el método `addConnection()` pongo el tag `@RequestBody` me funciona el test pero desde la Web deja de funcionar. ¿Cómo puedo simular el objeto que recibe el controlador con el mockMvc?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo visto, el formulario HTML envía los valores como parámetros al controlador. Al cambiar el mockMvc para pasar los valores como parámetros en vez de como json body, se ha arreglado el error.

El código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
    mockMvc.perform(post("/model/connection")
            .param("connectionId", "countingCamera1Conn")
            .param("path", "urlPath")
            .param("status", "IN")
            .param("username", "username")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated())
    ;
```